# Why are Web Services a preferred standard to achieve SOA?

Tags: web-services

I'm learning about web services and I read it is the standard way to archive a Service Oriented Architecture. 
Why are Web Services used so much to implement SOA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service is a self contained unit of functionality. You access that functionality over a well defined interface that the service exposes to the outside world.

SOA is (obviously) about service-orientation. It is an architectural pattern relying on loosely connected services that interract and colaborate to provide larger functionality than the individual services. Web services are just one way to implement SOA. You can just as well use message oriented middleware to obtain the same, or even have the services as processes on one machine.

Why web services are popular as a SOA implementation is because of history. Before SOA had a name, people were doing a similar thing using RPC. However RPC only works in a homogenous technology stack so soon after that XML-RPC appeared, then after that SOAP, and all sorts of specifications and programming standards to support different types of software talking to each other accross the network. So, many companies have turned to web services to interconnect different, heterogenous, legacy systems, with newly created solutions, or even software systems of their business partners.

Being the right thing at the right time (with acompanying standards to interconnect heterogenous systems) made web services the first tool being picked up by companies while trying to make the move to a SOA architecture. But you can have SOA implementations without necessarily resorting to using web services.